# Why does feature importance decrease for highly correlated variables?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, feature-selection, scikit-learn, cart

I am investigating the relationship between correlation between features and its impact on their feature importances using sklearn's DecisionTreeClassifier algorithm.

I manipulated the correlation of variables using the following function. This takes an existing feature from the dataset (Feature A), and creates a correlated feature (Feature B) which contains similar information with Feature A in addition to some noise:

```py
def create_highly_correlated_column(existing_column, correlation_coefficient, seed=0):
    """Create a highly correlated feature with an existing feature of equal cardinality."""
    
    np.random.seed(seed)
    noisy_column = existing_column.copy()
    noise_values = noisy_column.value_counts(normalize=True).index
    distribution = noisy_column.value_counts(normalize=True).tolist()
    noisy_column = noisy_column.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(noise_values, p=distribution) 
                                      if np.random.rand() >= correlation_coefficient else x)

    return noisy_column
```

So at correlation = 0, Feature B is essentially pure noise and at correlation = 1, Feature B is an exact duplicate of Feature A. Here is how the above function resembles the Pearson's correlation coefficient between two Features:

[image]

I then plotted a graph of the function's correlation coefficient vs feature importance of both Feature A and Feature B averaged over multiple RNG seeds. The following diagram shows the importances of Feature A (orange) and Feature B (blue):

[image: Feature Importances of original CatAge feature (orange) and correlated Noise (blue)]

As Feature B becomes highly correlated (~ >0.8), the feature importance of the Feature A starts to decrease quite a bit. I think the reason is because some splits which were originally determined by Feature A are now determined by Feature B, so the importance has in a way started to shift from Feature A to Feature B (becoming evenly split when the features are multicollinear).

However, this cutoff range which appears around 0.8 differs when Feature A is changed. For example, choosing to apply my function on a different Feature A produces a graph where the feature importance is only split when the correlated feature has a correlation value of 0.99.

Do different features admit a different degree of correlation before their feature importance begins to decrease? Which factors determine this?

*Note: Since the results from my plot are averaged over multiple seeds, then the feature importances for Feature B and Feature A are almost identical as correlation coefficient approaches 1.*

Comment: Good work refocusing, voted to reopen.  The different "correlation thresholds" might be an artifact of your flavor of noise?  Features with many unique values arguably(?) tend to get split on more often but expose more noise.  Can you tell us more about these two features you've tested with?  // What flavor of feature importance are you using here?

Comment: Thank you. I've tested this with all the features included in the Titanic dataset, and also with features in a larger dataset. The common relation with all of them, is that both Feature A and Feature B decrease in feature importance as correlation increases, though the magnitude of decrease in Feature A differs wildly. The variable used here is "CatAge" (binned Age values) with cardinality of 5, but there are features with both lower and higher cardinality that don't show the steep drop of that this feature has. Also the feature importance criterion is gini.